# Show secondary menu on custom page in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-navigation

I have a custom page whose link is on secondary menu page.

Main Menu
 - Secondary Menu
 - - Custom page

When user go to custom page, secondary menu hides. Because of that to back to secondary menu page user needs to first click on Main menu and then secondary menu. I want to make Secondary menus visible on that custom page, so that user can directly click secondary menu.

How can I do that ??

Answer (score 0):

You can place a block with the secondary menu in your custom page only, using the block configuration: admin>structure>block, find your secondary menu, configure it (display it on every pages you want), and then, place it on specific theme region.

I hope I'll help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to print into your custom page below code.

```
<?php print theme('links__system_secondary_menu', array('links' => $secondary_menu, 'attributes' => array('id' => 'secondary-menu', 'class' => array('links', 'inline', 'clearfix')), 'heading' => t('Secondary menu'))); ?>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

$menuItems = menu_tree_page_data('menu-name'); foreach($menuItems as $key => $m) { //check current active menu if ($m['link']['in_active_trail'] && $menuItems [$key]['below']) { $menu = menu_tree_output($menuItems [$key]['below']); } } //print the menu print $menu;

You can use this to show your menu on custom pages, you also add the HTML tags to make menu layout according theme.